# NoReverseMatch in url pattern-data is in tuple form

Tags: python, django

Django URL pattern not recognized due to tuple entry

I want to put a hyperlink in HTML code to redirect to a page with sending data with it. hyperlink path is dynamic so I used `{% url "check" book.id %}` in HTML code. book.id gives correct data but it appears in tuple format ('12',)

when I call particular page by writing static URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/check/12/` it works fine "check" as view area and 12 as an argument passed

how to use a dynamic path

views.py

```
def add(request):
    book = Readdata.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'result.html', {'books': book})

def check(request,id):
    return render(request,'result.html',{'result': id})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('add', views.add, name='add'),
    url(r'^check/(\d+)/$', views.check, name="delete_book"),
    url('', views.index, name="index")
]
```

html

```
<a href="{% url 'check' book.age %}">click </a> not working
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/check/21/">click </a> working
```

error-

> Reverse for 'check' with arguments '(21,)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['check']

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with tuples.

As the error says, you don't have a "check" URL that takes an argument "21". The only URL that takes an argument is "delete_book". "check" takes no arguments.

Comment: Right, the problem was with "delete_book", Thank you